geom_sf color multipolygons
I have multiplygon data read from a geojson file
geojson <- read_sf (filename)

Data looks like that:
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -16.64523 ymin: 27.23105 xmax: 39.81916 ymax: 65.99652
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  id                                                                    geometry
  <chr>                                                       <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
1 Coverage           (((-7.599085 33.35191, -7.813386 33.43519, -7.728468 33.51…
2 HighInterference   (((30.60789 42.13764, 30.638 42.22092, 30.75046 42.22092, …
3 LowInterference    (((24.75786 59.54255, 24.80001 59.62583, 24.96471 59.62583…
4 MediumInterference (((26.36263 58.87633, 26.40755 58.95961, 26.56905 58.95961…

Then I use geom_sf to show each row of data with its color:
library ("ggplot2")
library ("sf")
library ("rnaturalearth")
library ("rnaturalearthdata")
library ("ggspatial")
library ("geojsonR")

europe <- ne_countries (scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class (europe)

filename <- "geojson.geojson"

geojson <- read_sf (filename)

p <- ggplot () + geom_sf (data = europe)
p <- p + geom_sf (data = geojson[geojson$id == "Coverage", ], color = alpha ("green", 0.1), fill = alpha ("green", 0.1))
p <- p + geom_sf (data = geojson[geojson$id == "LowInterference", ], color = alpha ("yellow", 0.5), fill = alpha ("yellow", 0.5))
p <- p + geom_sf (data = geojson[geojson$id == "MediumInterference", ], color = alpha ("orange", 0.5), fill = alpha ("orange", 0.5))
p <- p + geom_sf (data = geojson[geojson$id == "HighInterference", ], color = alpha ("red", 0.5), fill = alpha ("red", 0.5))
p <- p + coord_sf (xlim = c(-20, 42), ylim = c(33, 72))
plot (p)

ggsave (paste (filename, ".pdf", sep = ""))
ggsave (paste (filename, ".png", sep = ""))

I have a feeling that is way to show a legend. There are not always all layers present in the file. The example shown has all, but any one or more might be missing. The legend can always have all possible values. I have a feeling it can be done, but I have no idea how.

Here is a geojson example:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {

            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                0,
                                40
                            ],
                            [
                                10,
                                50
                            ],
                            [
                                0,
                                60
                            ],
                            [
                                -10,
                                55
                            ],
                            [
                                0,
                                40
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "id": "Coverage"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {

            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                20,
                                45
                            ],
                            [
                                25,
                                50
                            ],
                            [
                                20,
                                60
                            ],
                            [
                                0,
                                50
                            ],
                            [
                                20,
                                45
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "id": "HighInterference"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {

            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                10,
                                35
                            ],
                            [
                                20,
                                35
                            ],
                            [
                                20,
                                40
                            ],
                            [
                                10,
                                40
                            ],
                            [
                                10,
                                35
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "id": "LowInterference"
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {

            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                30,
                                50
                            ],
                            [
                                40,
                                50
                            ],
                            [
                                40,
                                60
                            ],
                            [
                                30,
                                60
                            ],
                            [
                                30,
                                50
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "id": "MediumInterference"
        }
    ]
}


Edit:
Now, the whole R source is included. The sample is now fully reproducible with R source and geojson content.

Please provide a sample of your data in a reprdocuible format. E.g. use dput(head(geojson)) and dput(head(europe)) or similar.

@Friede For europe, it is simple europe <- ne_countries (scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf"). For geojson, it is a large file. I will try to make a short working example of that large file.

Ahh, you are referring to {rnaturalearth}. That does return the "world", but I understand where are you coming from. :) Please do that.

Yeah, I had only europe selected in ne_countries function at first, but then North Africa, and Middle East were missing in my view and it did not look right. :)

You could set fill and colour in the aesthetics and apply manual fill/color scales like so:
europe <- ne_countries (scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf",
                        continent = 'Europe' ## filter for Europe
                        )
geojson <- read_sf('geojson.geojson')


color_mapping <- c(
  Coverage = alpha ("green", 0.1),
  LowInterference = alpha ("yellow", 0.5),
  MediumInterference = alpha ("orange", 0.5),
  HighInterference = alpha ("red", 0.5)
)

## make the id column a factor, so legend entries are displayed
## even w/o any observation in this category (`drop = FALSE`)
geojson$id <-factor(geojson$id, levels = names(color_mapping))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = europe) +
  geom_sf(data = geojson, aes(fill = id, color = id)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_mapping,
                    drop = FALSE, ## display legend entry even w/o observations
                    ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = color_mapping, drop = FALSE)


Note: scale_..._manual also takes an argument na.value to set a fill/color for NAs.


Thanks for your answer. I tried to apply your solution to my example, but I failed. First, I do not know how to make polygons with the same alpha as fill. Second, I do not know how to handle some files that do not have some of the categories (e.g. missing HighInterference).

Thanks. The solution now works. There is still a minor issue with the legend. If some type of polygon is missing, then the legend is also grey. Is it possible to show the color in the legend although the data for that color is missing?

I have found a way to show missing values in legend. Missing id need to be added with no data liek this geojson <- st_as_sf (geojson %>% complete (id), crs = st_crs (4326)).

Not too sure what you ar looking for. Simply aes(fill=id) in ggplot2::geom_sf()?
Code
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110L, returnclass = "sf")
geojson <- st_as_sfc(str_geojson, GeoJSON = TRUE) |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  st_cast("POLYGON", group_or_split = TRUE, warn = FALSE)
geojson$id <- jsonlite::fromJSON(str_geojson)$features$id
box <- st_bbox(geojson)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = geojson, aes(fill = id, alpha = .2)) +
  xlim(box[1L] - 10L, box[3L] + 10L) +
  ylim(box[3L] - 10L, box[4L] + 10L) +
  scale_alpha(guide = "none")

Output

Note
str_geojson <- '{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                0,
                40
              ],
              [
                10,
                50
              ],
              [
                0,
                60
              ],
              [
                -10,
                55
              ],
              [
                0,
                40
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "Coverage"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                20,
                45
              ],
              [
                25,
                50
              ],
              [
                20,
                60
              ],
              [
                0,
                50
              ],
              [
                20,
                45
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "HighInterference"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                10,
                35
              ],
              [
                20,
                35
              ],
              [
                20,
                40
              ],
              [
                10,
                40
              ],
              [
                10,
                35
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "LowInterference"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                30,
                50
              ],
              [
                40,
                50
              ],
              [
                40,
                60
              ],
              [
                30,
                60
              ],
              [
                30,
                50
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "MediumInterference"
    }
  ]
}'

